# Split mail domain

Tags: email

I have our mail in a hosted exchange environment.  We have an internal application server which I need mail delivered directly to it for autoprocessing.  The application does not allow pop configuration, I need the actual email delivered to the server for it to then be autoprocessed.  I am looking to have some specific email addresses (but not all) routed to this server to allow some auto processing of some inbound emails.

We are a small company - limited infrastructure.  Only 1 server.  No DMZ etc...

This is the solution I have thought of:

I have 1 domain.  Create a sub-domain (eg mail.domain.com), and forward the emails initially for email1@domain.com to email1@mail.domain.com, and then have those emails routed directly to the mail server.  As we do not have a DMZ, I was thinking of using MessageLabs, and having them route mail to the sub domain (test.domain.com) to the company firewall - and only allow connections from MessageLabs.

Any thoughts?  I'm trying to not overcomplicate this, and essentially just want 4 email addresses to be delivered to a specific mail server.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since fetchmail 6.3.3, it supports IMAP IDLE feature according to its manpage.
I suggest you to use one email server with IMAP and use fetchmail on your internal server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have something similar in place at the moment which is working okay - the negative is the time stamps are when the email is downloaded to the final mail server.  that was why I was thinking along the lines of a subdomain.